# React onClick not working in device with <Image>

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to add a border to the image when its clicked, like a radio button, but only with an image.
The code works perfectly on web but when I try to click the image on the device it doesn't do anything!
I tried to do Alert.alert() and it's like it doesn't register the click.

```
let stylereg_na = { borderRadius: 3, height: hp('7%'), width: wp('25%')};
let stylereg_eu = { borderRadius: 3, height: hp('7%'), width: wp('25%')};
if(regNA)
{
  stylereg_na = {borderWidth: 2, borderColor:'black', borderRadius: 3, height: hp('8%'), width: wp('26%')};
}
return (

    <Image style={stylereg_na} source={na} onClick={() => 
    {
      if(regNA)
        setRegNAStatus(false);
      else
      {
        setRegNAStatus(true);
      }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap it Touchable component like this

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => alert('Pressed!')}>
  <Image style={stylereg_na} source={na} />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>;
```

refer to the documentation if you wanna learn more about it, like TouchableHighlight or TouchableOpacity https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback